# Simple mapping of inner object without identity

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Who can help me map this seemingly simple object hierarchy using nHibernate?

```
[Document]
 identity-field
 [DocumentHeader] 
     field1
     field2
     [Recipients]
```

The point to note here is that [DocumentHeader] has no identity and is considered a part of the [Document] entity. 
I think it isn't a component either because it has associations with other reference objects.

Can this hierarchy be mapped with nHibernate as-is?
Can [Document] and [DocumentHeader] be mapped to the same table?

I am using the fluent variant for configuration and IAutoMappingOverrides.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`DocumentHeader` is a component in your case. Nothing prevents you from having references or collections inside the component.

Comment: The samples I have seen on Component didn't have a object association. I guess this is a wrong assumption from my side then, I will test this and give some feedback. Thanks...